# Magento 2 product import error

Tags: magento2, import, importexport, system.log

I get:

> *General system exception happened 
>   Additional data: URL key for specified store already exists.*

error when trying to import products with csv.

my csv file is passing check data process but when I press import button I get this error.

Is there any sugetion for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

This could be the solution according to Github ([Link to Github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1471))

1. Keep the URL key column blank, and make sure you have added the correct category name with upper and lower case letter.
2. Make sure the total length of your categories CSV column is shorter than **255 characters**. You can check your url_key length too, but I haven't run into issues with my data set on that one.

Answer (score 3):

I got this solved by running the below query to the database:

`delete from catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id=98 and value="";`

where **98** is the **attribute_id** of **url_path** attribute.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: i tried the above...and deleted all data in catalog_product_entity table still id seems to increment from previous values after import

Comment: Did you check the attribute_id for url_path from the eav_attribute table

Answer (score 2):

For those that are importing the products via a CSV file or a excel spreadsheet and it was working before but suddenly stop to work.

You probably have a PRODUCT or a CATEGORY been uploaded that already contain the same default URL KEY. Check the products or categories that you manually added or updated. Check their URL KEY attribute.

A painful way to find the error is to separate your spreadsheet in parts, and run them separately until you have a few lines to check.

Answer (score 2):

Probably issue comes on working category URL.

please ignore backslash('/') in categories column "Default Category/Shop/"

Wrong categories assign = Default Category/Shop/
Right categories assign = Default Category/Shop