# Magento 2: Unable to import products due to Invalid URL Key Error

Tags: magento2.3, import-products

I have made an upload file with both simple and configurable products.
I have also specified all the necessary configurable_variations.

**I am using the Add/Update import behaviour**

When I click *Check Data* there are no errors in the Validation results

[image: Validation Result]

However, when I click import, I get Maximum error count has been reached or system error is occurred!and Invalid URL key.

[image]

The url_key column for all the products is empty.

So far, the solutions like this [one](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148092/product-with-specified-super-products-sku-not-found-in-rows-when-reimporti) that I have come across are not helping.

How can go about solving this error and import products successfully.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this issue? We're have the exact same issue importing into 2.4

Comment: It has been a while! But what I recall is that there were issues with the category url column. When those were solved, import was possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issue may be in your category url column. In my case there were two consecutive commas in category URL.

Answer (score 0):

Found something related to this question
please refer this link.

[Magento 2 product import error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101999/magento-2-product-import-error)

hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Dimple Panchal 
I came across that link but it wasn't helpful, what is working for me at moment is breaking down the one file into multiple files.

This seems to products imported successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Either 2 consecutive commas are in the Category URL or you may have the Category URL ending with a comma - this was an error for me that I resolved when I became aware the Category can't end with a comma

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with the product import - it was in the import file itself. For one product, one of the categories was specified as "Default Category/", which is an obvious error, but almost impossible to spot in the file with a few thousand lines and multiple categories for each product.

I think Magento might be doing a better job with providing more details for the error, but in the meantime, my recommendation to find what exactly triggers the error, place debug stopping point at `vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Observer/CategoryUrlPathAutogeneratorObserver.php:validateUrlKey()` and go upstream to find what lines triggers an error.

Hope it saved someone a few minutes